# Add extra card to Stripe customer, in Curl?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to get my head around this. Basically, it looks like there are a ton of PHP/Ruby/Node etc modules, but again a very lacking Perl one (*Business::Stripe*, that hasn't been updated since 2012!)

So, I've resorted to doing my own updates using curl. It's a bit messy, as I've used the Perl module for the basic customer creation, and then a curl query to subscribe them to a package (as the Perl module doesn't offer "plans" as a feature)

```
  use Business::Stripe;
  my $stripe     = Business::Stripe->new(
    -api_key         => $CFG->{stripe_mode}
  );

  my $cid = $stripe->customers_create(
    card => $_[2],
    email => $in->{email},
    description => 'For Site Membership'
  );
```

Then subscribe with:

```
   my $sub = `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions -u $key: -d plan=name_$in->{package} -d customer=$cid`;
   my $json = decode_json($sub);
```

Now this works... but the problem I'm having, is how do I add a new card to this customer?

I can get the customer object back fine:

```
   my $sub = `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_xxxx -u sk_test_KEY:`;
   my $json = decode_json($sub);
```

...and this gives me all the information on the user. But how do I add a new card for them? I have already got the code that asks for all the card information, and then passes back the token (where the card is associated with), but I'm stumped on the next step. I've tried googling around and I'm not coming up with anything helpful (there are loads of posts about it with example of ruby/node/php, but none is pure curl :/)

Comment: You'd probably be better off using LWP or something rather than shelling out to curl, for performance/security reasons.

Comment: I recommend you use [Net::API::Stripe](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::API::Stripe), which is the most comprehensive perl library for Stripe with over 200 modules covering all aspects of Stripe API. I posted an answer below with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Eugh, I knew this would happen!!!! Literally minutes after posting this, I came across:

https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object

So the solution is to just pass the token along via:

```
my $res = `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/$USER->{stripe_customer_id}/sources -u $key: -d source=$in->{token}`;
```

...and then decode:

```
my $json = decode_json($res);
```

...and this returns an object with the new card:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'object' => 'card',
      'address_zip' => undef,
      'address_state' => undef,
      'fingerprint' => 'lRvQRC14boreOKjk',
      'brand' => 'Visa',
      'tokenization_method' => undef,
      'dynamic_last4' => undef,
      'address_zip_check' => undef,
      'address_line2' => undef,
      'funding' => 'credit',
      'exp_month' => 12,
      'address_city' => undef,
      'metadata' => {},
      'id' => 'card_xxxx',
      'country' => 'US',
      'name' => 'andy@domain.co.uk',
      'exp_year' => 2019,
      'address_line1' => undef,
      'address_country' => undef,
      'cvc_check' => 'pass',
      'customer' => 'cus_xxxx',
      'last4' => '4242',
      'address_line1_check' => undef
    };
```

...and sure enough, it now shows the extra card associated with the user:

[image]

Hopefully this helps save someone else the hassle :)

Also, I came across a much better Perl module for doing it programmatically:

http://search.cpan.org/~rconover/Net-Stripe-0.30/lib/Net/Stripe.pm

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use [Net::API::Stripe](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::API::Stripe), which is the most comprehensive perl library for Stripe with over 200 modules covering all aspects of Stripe API.

To achieve what you want, you would do:

```perl
my $stripe = Net::API::Stripe->new({
    conf_file => './stripe-settings.json',
    # Switch it to 1 once you are ready to go live
    livemode => 0,
    ignore_unknown_parameters => 1,
    expand => 'all',
}) || die( Net::API::Stripe->error );

my $cust = $stripe->customers( create => {
    email => $email,
    description => $description,
    payment_method => $payment_method,
}) || die( $stripe->error );

my $sub = $stripe->subscriptions( create => {
    customer => $cust,
    items    => [
        price => "price_1Le1oa2eZvKYlo2CuD7mwpZu",
    ]
}) || die( $stripe->error );

Full disclosure, I am the author of that perl module.
```

Comment: Thanks - only 5 years too late for my project :) Hopefully it helps someone else though (pretty sure I tried your module a while back - but it took AGES to load? even from SSH)

Comment: @Andrew Newby, not surprising given the very large volume of methods implemented to mirror the very extensive Stripe API. Now, most methods load dynamically.

Comment: fair enough - I'll give it another go on my next project :) thanks